# Only run the next validator if the previous was true - typeorm

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to know if it is possible to run only the next validator when the previous one was passed.

Example of my `DTO`:

```
export class UserBooksDTO {
  @UserExists()
  username: string

  @BookExists()
  @MatchUserBook()
  id: string
}
```

As you can see, my `id` has two validators but when the `@BookExists()` fails the `@MatchUserBook` is also running.
At the end, I'm having two error messages but I only want to show the @BookExists error.

Comment: are you using ```@nestjs/class-validator``` or ```class-validator``` package?

Comment: you can pass validationOptions to custom validators ```stopAtFirstError``` may be what you are looking for. See docs here, https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#readme

Comment: @vicki I'm using `class-validator`. I tried to apply the `stopAtFirstError` but is not working. Where do I need to put this `stopAtFirstError`, can you give an example pls?

Comment: it works If I use not custom validators like `IsString()` `IsNumber()`..